# twitter bootstrap form-control how to inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can i make the "2014" and "SS" form-control are "col-md-6",form no class,it look like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="year">年份*</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="year" class="input-group date">
                <input id="yearVal" name="year" type="text" class="form-control" readonly/><span
                    class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <select id="season" name="season" class="form-control">
                <option value="false">SS</option>
                <option value="true">FW</option>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: my page]

Comment: You have a typo `<<div class="col-md-6">`, there are two `<`.

Comment: @Caau Can you specify what exactly you want to render?

Comment: @uDaY I think he want the `input` and the `select` next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a space for label in season.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="year">年份*</label>
              <div id="year" class="input-group date">
                <input id="yearVal" name="year" type="text" class="form-control" readonly=""><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label for="season">&nbsp;</label>
            <select id="season" name="season" class="form-control">
                <option value="false">SS</option>
                <option value="true">FW</option>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See the output in this [**bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/CXdEsMptP5)
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Simply Use col-md-12 for label like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
       <label for="year">年份*</label>
</div>
```

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/iylTAORKz9)

FULL HTML:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="year">年份*</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div id="year" class="input-group date">
                            <input id="yearVal" name="year" type="text" class="form-control" readonly /><span
                                class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select id="season" name="season" class="form-control">
                            <option value="false">SS</option>
                            <option value="true">FW</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```